# What regex expression should be used with preg_replace to replace associated text?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

G'day,

I'm trying to figure out how to replace some text, using the following as an example:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, [annotate ref="C1849"]consectetur 
adipisicing elit[/annotate], sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt 
ut labore et [annotate ref="C9437"]dolore[/annotate] magna 
[fred ref="38"]aliqua[/fred].
```

The text within [] is to be replaced, dependant on the value immediately after the opening [. In this case the objective is to replace the annotate 'tags'. The new text would be html tags, possibly span or similar, as well as inserting some html attributes (class, id, etc).

I can replace the [annotate and the [/annotate] via str_replace(). I can also replace all "] via the str_replace(). However I don't wish to replace all occurrences of "] only when "] is associated with a [annotate, so I was thinking regex with preg_replace() would be more appropriate for replacing the "]. I played around with lookbehind until I realised that lookbehind only deals with fixed length strings.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to allow for newlines and carriage returns?

Comment: Between a [ and ] there will not be any new lines or carriage returns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it's a bad idea to use regex to parse xml-like data (tags/closing tags/attributes): some sort of DOM parser is much better.

However, for a quick and dirty fix to your problem, try:

```
$text = 'Lorem ipsum .....';
$patterns = array('/\[annotate([^\]]*)\]/',
                  '/\[\/annotate\]/');
$replacements = array('<span blahablah \1>',
                      '</span>');
echo preg_replace($patterns, $replace, $text);
```

`$patterns` has the first element being the opening tag and the latter being the closing tag.
The opening tag captures everything after the `annotate` until the corresponding closing `]`, and preserves it in `replacements` using `\1`.

One reason I say regex isn't the best idea for tag parsing is that if the `annotate` contains a stray `]` that'll screw up the regex.

E.g. `[annotate extraattribute="alblasd]"]` will be cut off at the first `]` instead of the second.

Comment: @Metalskin: If you build your own DOM based on [ and ], then yes. But normally DOM Parser refers to a HTML DOM Document, so no. I think mathematical coffee just wanted to point out that *if* your text is actually HTML, a regex would have problems to deal with it.

Comment: @mathematical.coffee. Thanks mate, this should work for me. I have control over any values for the attributes as it's system generated not user entered. :edit: i deleted my previous comment asking about the use of a DOM for [ and ] thinking I could repost it better but hakre posted a reply as i was doing so, thought I should explain.

Comment: @hakre thanks for the clarification, I would rather use a DOM parser if I could but I didn't think I would be able to with the [ and ] usage without extending the existing parser.

Comment: yeah, I don't have much experience with DOM parsers being a regex hack-and-slasher myself (I only do code for personal use so have no qualms about trying to parse HTML-like stuff hackily with regex and deal with the odd mis-parsing), but I (wrongly?) assumed that a DOM parser would allow you to set the delimiters to `[]` from `<>` (seems reasonable enough!). It's just that 'use-DOM-not-regex' is a general statement that gets made on all regex/html-type questions so I felt like keeping with StackOverflow tradition :)

Comment: @mathematical.coffee I think it depends on the implementation and whether it allows either options to set the use of [ and ] or if it can be extended and overridden to allow custom functionality. The language I'm using is PHP and while I believe that the inbuilt DOM parser can be extended, I will not be doing so due to time constraints. If I have time to revisit this I may look into it (we all know one never has time to revisit code later on) :-)